# What type of sensors have complex Gaussian noise?

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, gaussian, sensor

What type of sensors have complex Gaussian noise?

Do strain gauges also exhibit such noise?

Comment: Do you have a sensor that delivers complex values?

Comment: I am not using any experiment. I am trying to simulate a scenario where strain gauge is being used to measure displacement and velocity.  I assumed that the noise in the strain gauge is complex Gaussian. In order to justify the selection of this type of noise ( and not simple Gaussian), I wanted to know whether strain gauges exhibit complex Gaussian noise.

Comment: You lost me. How does a strain gauge give you a complex signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No physical system suffers from, or produces, complex Gaussian noise. Quadrature systems can be modelled as being complex, with the in-phase branch corresponding to a real value, and the quadrature branch corresponding to an imaginary value. If each branch presents Gaussian (thermal) noise, then the noise can be modelled as complex Gaussian, too. However, this is just a modelling technique: the actual physical noise is never complex.

To answer your first question: sensors that operate in quadrature, and are modelled using the complex envelope, can be modelled as having complex noise.